# Spring REST get list from another class

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am new to both Spring and the REST API overall but I am now trying to make one. So from my controller, I want to return a list of files that another method returns in another class. The code probably says more then I can explain:

```
   @RequestMapping("/backup")
    public @ResponseBody List<FileInfo> backupFiles() {
        return //Here i want to return the list of files
    }
```

This is in my restController the "method" i want to return a list of FileInfo and today it already exists a method that does this that looks like this

```
 private List<String> listBackupFiles() {
    List<FileInfo> files = util.listBackupFilesInLocalDir(localStorage);
    fileNameToSize = files.stream()
                          .collect(toMap(f -> f.name, f -> f.size));
    return files.stream()
                .map(f -> f.name)
                .collect(toList());
}
```

So basically, I want to when someone goes to `/backup` I want the above method to trigger and return the list of files to my `restController` that then returns it to the requester. I don't know if this is even possible or if there is a better way to do this. I take any tips on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: I see that, the service listBackupFiles() returns a String, but in your rest controller you are returning List<FileInfo>. This is not right!

Comment: You need to create an instance of the other class and then call the method.  If the `listBackupFiles()` method is in a separate class from your controller, you could make a new instance of that class in the controller or if you are using spring beans, you can @Autowire the spring managed instance into your controller.

Comment: you need to put the list in json before return, and use @Autowire to access the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller would be:

```
  // @RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody
  @RestController
    public class BackupController {  

        @Autowired
        private BackupService backupService;

        // you don't need @ResponseBody as you use @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/backup")
        public List<FileInfo> backupFiles() {
            return backupService.listBackupFiles()
        }
    }
```

The service interface would be:

```
public interface BackupService {

     public List<FileInfo> listBackupFiles();
}
```

The service implementation would be:

```
@Service
public class BackupServiceImpl implements BackupService {

    public List<FileInfo> listBackupFiles() {
        // localStorage come from
        // maybe Util has it as static method, else inject it
        return util.listBackupFilesInLocalDir(localStorage);
    }
}
```

Hope was helpful :)

Comment: i get duplicate class error on the "BackupService" class and renaming fixes nothing. feels like this would work but cant get past this